# Struggling to run commands on minting test website

Tags: javascript, java, ethereum, solidity, ethernet

firstly I am new to both java and web3 so sorry if this causes some frustration.
I am trying to learn about both smart contracts and nfts so have decided to try and code a testing site for minting.

The problem I am running into is when I execute commands within console on my website (using terminal to run a locally hosted site) I get a type error if they contain commands that exist within the smart contract.

For example if I run a simple "await contract.methods.totalSupply().call()" I get an error station "VM479:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'totalSupply')."

More frustratingly my button which calls a safeMint function does a similar thing, when clicking the button I receive "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'safeMint')"

Here is my smart contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.4.2/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.4.2/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.4.2/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.4.2/utils/Counters.sol";

contract Mugs is ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;
uint256 public mintRate = 0.1 ether;
uint public MAX_SUPPLY = 3;

constructor() ERC721("Mugs", "MUG") {}

function _baseURI() internal pure override returns (string memory) {
    return "https";
}

function safeMint(address to) public payable {
    require(totalSupply() < MAX_SUPPLY, "No more NFTS available.");
    require(msg.value >= mintRate, "The mint price is 0.1!");
    _tokenIdCounter.increment();
    uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
    _safeMint(to, tokenId);
}

// The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId)
    internal
    override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
{
    super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
}

function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
    public
    view
    override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
    returns (bool)
{
    return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
}

function withdraw() public onlyOwner{
    require(address(this).balance > 0, "Balance is zero"); 
    payable(owner()).transfer(address(this).balance);
}
}
```

and below is my site.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Mugs</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>Wallet Address - <span id="wallet-address"></span></p>
        <button id="mint">Mint</button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // connect meta and get users address
var account = null;
var contract = null;
const ABI = [];
const ADDRESS = "0x02b60bA2a8238F0a80ecA444608256Ee7f551bCD";
(async () => {
    if (window.ethereum) {
        await window.ethereum.send('eth_requestAccounts');
        window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);

        var accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
        account = accounts[0];
        document.getElementById('wallet-address').textContent = account;

        contract = new web3.eth.getAccounts()

        document.getElementById('mint').onclick = () => {
            contract.methods.safeMint(account).send({from: account, value: "10000000000000000"});
                    }
    }
})();



    </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

I was adding the ABI but for the sake of minimising space I removed it. I've deployed the contract to the ropsten test net.

Hopefully this is easy enough to understand. Thank you very much for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to load a contract while you are getting accounts.
`contract = new web3.eth.getAccounts()`. getAccounts returns a list of accounts the node controls.
Instead you need to use web3.eth.Contract. [Further reading.](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html)